# What does "angle they wish to cover" mean?

Tags: meaning

Context:

> The University of Maryland has a team of academic experts educating the media about Valentine’s Day no matter what **angle they wish to cover**. There I’ve read that many people choose Valentine’s Day for getting married. Can you imagine? The list of celebrities who’ve done this includes Elton John and Meg Ryan. And quite a lot of famous people have been born on that day!

Comment: It is a metaphor which hypothesises any topic in the form of a geometrical figure. The various approaches one might take to it being regarded as different "angles" on the subject. It is a very frequently used, everyday idiom in English.

Comment: Dictionary (OD) defines angle = a particular way of approaching or considering an issue or problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> angle they wish to cover

The point of view the media will take. So, from what perspective they will tell the story, and what specific elements of the topic they will cover.

For example, if the topic is Valentine's Day you could cover a story about the amount of flowers sold.